# how to answer the JavaScript in an asp.net mvc view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage))
{
    <script>
        $('#modalError').modal('show');
    </script>

    Response.Write("<script>alert('hello');</script>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('hello');</script>");
}
```

Where check if Model.Error Message is different from empty, so I an alert to the user, but none of the forms submitted by the condition if this working, how can it be done?

already I tried so:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["erro"] as string))
{
    <script>alert(@ViewData["erro"]);</script>

}
```

This and a part of the view.

My controller this way:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ErrorMessage))
                ViewData["erro"] = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ErrorMessage) ? model.ErrorMessage : null;

            return this.View(model);
        }
```

I want to display a javascript message because I will use the modal Bootstrap

Comment: Where is the code you shared located? Is it in a View or in an Action method? We need that info to be able to help you correctly.

Comment: Also why are you outputting script tags with Response.Write()? We need to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Botonomous, to give a message to the user, "name or invalid email"

Comment: @SomadinaMbadiwe it is a view

Comment: Please write what you are trying to do? In what case do you want to use it?

Comment: @Alexandre, see my answer on how you should go about it. As pointed out by above, it's not clear why you're doing what you're doing; so I've restricted myself to helping you solve the exact problem you posted.

Comment: if you build the validation into your view model, you can do simple validation   by using MVC annotations on your model and reflect them in your view appropriately - here is a link that might help http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/performing-simple-validation-cs

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do with this code, other than to say your taking the wrong approach. Validation, both client side and server side is built into MVC and you should start by reading [Adding Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: @AT-2016 In fact is not validation is an authentication, Model.ErrorMessage returns a message if the user and password is invalid, so I just want to display a javascript message to the User saying it fou not authenticated, and the way I'm doing as the above code is not working out as not display any alert on the screen.

Comment: JS posted the answer that you're looking for if you want to inform the user of a model error, like your post suggests that you are. Why you would want to should an alert specifically instead of just printing the ValidationSummary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alexandre Lima,
As pointed out in comments by others and I agree too, not sure if your approach is right or if it is then we need more information, that said, You have the following options

1. Use simple data validations on your view models to notify users of
   an invalid email - this is built into MVC for you - MVC's data
   annotation. Here are links
   http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/performing-simple-validation-cs
2. From your comment, looks like you want to display something on login
   failures , meaning your server code got back saying `Auth failed`,
   if that is the case, am assuming here you have something like this
   on your controller code

   ```
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel login)
   {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         //you call your service to get back the result

         if(!NotAValidUser)
         { 
            ModelState.AddModelError("LoginFailed", "The user name and or password is incorrect.")
         }
      }
   }
   ```

   *in your View*

   ```
   @Html.ValidationMessage("LoginFailed") // this will display the above message
   ```

Comment: I want to do with javascript to display a modal Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If it's a View, then you might be better off using Javascript/JQuery. To do that, you'll need to add a hidden field somewhere in your HTML and set the value to `Model.ErrorMessage`. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdError" value="@Model.ErrorMessage" />
```

Then at the end of your HTML body, you add the Javascript code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var errorStr = $("#hdError").val();
    if (errorStr) {
        alert("hello"); //or any other alert message
    } 
});
</script>
```